# Error Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, excepciones, build.gradle

¿A alguien le ha salido este error?, busqué alguna solución pero las que encontré, no me sirvieron

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformJackWithJackForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.core.JackToolchain$ToolchainException: Jack configuration exception.
>     Property 'jack.library.output.dir' (in Options): 'case insensitive wrapper' VFS format in directory 'C:\Users\LUISFRANCISCO\AndroidStudioProjects\SinFilarRegional\app\build\intermediates\incremental\transformJackWithJackForDebug' is wrong: file 'C:\Users\LUISFRANCISCO\AndroidStudioProjects\SinFilarRegional\app\build\intermediates\incremental\transformJackWithJackForDebug\index' does not exist (required because 'jack.library' (defined in Options) is set to true and 'jack.library.output.container' (defined in Options) is set to 'dir')

----------------------GRADLE--------------------

```
`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.luisfrancisco.sinfilarregional"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
```

Comment: Luis, agrega tu build.gradle. y realiza el [tour]

Comment: mmm estas usando el jack de audio?

Comment: @Maguz no, todo estaba funcionando bien y creo que empezó cuando actualice android Studio